# parse static text from <option> tags, then add the text (numbers) to a new price field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to fetch some numbers from an output in a select box and, .each over all of the selects every time I .change() the select box, and keep a running total of my amounts.

I'm missing something here in my code.

Here is my working example thus far.

http://jsfiddle.net/HdaMQ/

It's working partially. I'm failing to understand how to get both of the  boxes selected values and add them. (there could be more than 2 available to the user)

I'm not too savvy with using regex, so I'm slicing and dicing my strings until I get the exact value I need.

The ultimate goal here, is if a user changes their select options, the price will update accordingly and know exactly how much they will be spending.

Comment: Why not just add the prices as the `value=""` on the `<option>` tags? All you have to do then is do a parseInt and add them all together. At the moment you're using that as the index which doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: @Marko just said what I was thinking.  Use `value` for what it's there for.

Comment: You should not be in a position to have to parse numbers out of a text field to make that work. Those should be immediately available to you, e.g. in the form of `data` attributes (if you can't just use the `value` as already stated). If you have no control over the HTML of the page, then make a noise.

Comment: I'm doing some voodoo with OSCommerce and,  unfortunately, changing the value isn't available to edit. therefor, I'm forced to hack away at it with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Put your values in properly, then changed your option select function to something like this:

```
  var sum = 0;
  $("option:selected").each(function(index) {
       //alert($(this).prop("value"));
       sum += parseFloat($(this).prop("value"));
       alert(sum); //this alerts for each iteration, so you'll want to remove it
  });
```